# Angular *ngIf not updated with component method

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

When using a function to show/hide with `*ngIf` the block is not updated in the html.
when rendering the block to check the value (`{{contactInfoValid(contact)}}`) it is updated correctly, the `*ngIf` is not being triggered

HTML

```
<mat-form-field>
            <input matInput  type="text"
                      [(ngModel)]="contact.info" required>               
            <mat-error *ngIf="contactInfoValid(contact) == false">
               email not correct
            </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Component

```
  contactInfoValid(contact) {
    if (contact.hasValidInfo) {
       return true;
       }

    return false;
  }
```

The `mat-error` is never shown.

A FormControl cannot be used in this specific case since it is used in a dynamic grid

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem, for example on stackblitz?

Comment: @MikeS. https://angular-yhj6mj.stackblitz.io

Comment: made a mistake in by example, issue is not reproduced. Probably elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<mat-error>` component need an `ErrorStateMatcher` in order to display anything. There's a good article about this here; https://itnext.io/materror-cross-field-validators-in-angular-material-7-97053b2ed0cf

In short you need to specify `[errorStateMatcher]="myErrorStateMatcher"` on the form field that you're validating.

```
<mat-form-field>
   <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="contact.info" required
        [errorStateMatcher]="myErrorStateMatcher">
   <mat-error *ngIf="contactInfoValid(contact) == false">
       email not correct
   </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Normally ErrorStateMatcher works with FormControls, but if you want to use ngModel you can provide custom ErrorStateMatcher that have access to the data you need in order to display error messages. Below is a simplified example of this;

```
export class RuleErrorStateMatcher<T> implements ErrorStateMatcher {
    constructor(private editControl: IValidatableEditControl<T>) { }

    isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
        return this.editControl && this.editControl.model && !this.editControl.model.isValid;
    }
}

export interface IValidatableEditControl<T> {
    model: ValidationGeneric<T>;
}

export class ValidationGeneric<T>   {
    public value: T;
    public isValid: boolean;
}
```

If you try another html tag than mat-error you will see that your ngIf is probably working;

```
<span *ngIf="contactInfoValid(contact) == false">
        email not correct
</span>
```

Comment: Tried the span and that's working, this seems to be my problem. I'll try to fix and then accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

it could be by design as described [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/18430)

workaround is add FormControl like this instaed of binding to [(ngModel)]

```
email = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]);

<div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Enter your email</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="pat@example.com" [formControl]="email" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="email.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```